# Prototype/JQuery mixup with Grails formRemote

Tags: jquery, grails, prototypejs

I'm trying to rearrange certain of my forms and I have a weird issue
with one of them.
I've always used jquery instead of prototype so the jquery plugin is
installed and configured, my layout has a `<g:javascript
library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>` tag in its head, and Config.groovy
contains the `grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"` line.
So far so good.

Now I have a g:formRemote declared like this in my page:

```
<g:formRemote id="signUpForm" name="signUpForm" 
    url="[controller:'user', action:'register']" 
    onLoading="showRegistrationProgress()" 
    onComplete="hideRegistrationProgress()" 
    onSuccess="processRegistrationResponse(data)">
...
</g:formRemote>
```

But when I click the submit button, it completely bypasses the jquery
event handlers and does a standard non-ajax submit.

When I look at the javascript debugger in Chrome, I notice the
following error message when I submit my form: "Ajax not defined".
And indeed when I look at the generated HTML, I see that the form
looks like this:

```
<form onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/kodesk/user/register',...)" 
    method="POST" 
    action="/kodesk/user/register" 
    id="signUpForm" name="signUpForm">
....
</form>
```

Where does this "new Ajax.Request" come from? Isn't it prototype code?

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing moving the `<g:javascript library="jquery" />` down into your view instead of the layout.  I've noticed this solves the issue for me in the past.  Also try running a `clean` before you try the `run-app` again.

Comment: It works for formRemote but it breaks my event handlers because I have some jQuery code in both my layout and my page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work after I read this post: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/newb-ajax-jquery-question-td1386031.html

I just added `<g:setProvider library="jquery"/>` to my page head, and now it works. I still don't know why it didn't work before but this solution is good enough for me.